# Reading .wav file in Matlab Coder

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wav, matlab-deployment

I want to read an audio file with *matlab coder*. The problem is that `wavread()` is not supported, but as this is a pretty essential part of any audio coding I am thinking that there must be another way to achieve this? **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your use case?  If you really just want to run the generated code in a MEX-function within MATLAB you can use coder.extrinsic to call wavread.  This will not work outside of the MATLAB environment.

Outside the MATLAB environment, you will need to use custom C code integration.

Answer (score 1):

The WAV file format is fairly simple & widely documented [for example here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).
You can use the low-level file IO functions, `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fseek` to read the file, assuming these are themselves available. This is exactly what `wavread()` does internally - take a look at the source.

Comment: Unfortunately `fopen()` is not available in Matlab Coder. Otherwise it would have been the easiest option.. There seems to be some sort of integration with c-code that is needed, which is something I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` is now supported starting from Matlab 2013a. [See here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html).

Comment: I wanted this to be a comment to the above answer but I was not able to do that.