# How to extract data from a WAV file for use in an FFT

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft, wav

I'm looking for a way to extract data from a WAV file that will be useful for an FFT algorithm I'm trying to implement. So far what I have are a bunch of hex values for left and right audio channels, but I am a little lost on how to translate this over to time and frequency domains for an FFT.

Here's what I need for example:

```
3.6 2.6
2.9 6.3
5.6 4.0
4.8 9.1
3.3 0.4
5.9 4.8
5.0 2.6
4.3 4.1
```

And this is the prototype of the function taking in the data for the FFT:

```
void fft(int N, double (*x)[2], double (*y)[2])
```

Where N is the number of points for the FFT, x is a pointer to the time-domain samples, y is a pointer to the frequency-domain samples.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already determined frequency of the data using the WAVE format, specified here: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/?  This link came from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499270/reading-wav-file-in-matlab-coder

Comment: Unless you're writing your own FFT for academic reasons, check out http://www.fftw.org/. And for reading wave files: http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/

Comment: @oexcz - just to be clear, the time-domain samples are your input (the decode wav file) and the frequency-domain samples are your output. That's what the FFT does - converts from time-domain to frequency domain - right?

Comment: @hooleyhoop, Yes, that's what the FFT does.  But strictly speaking an FFT has complex numbers as its output.  When talking about audio, it is typical to look at the magnitude (absolute value of complex freq-domain samples) or the power (square of the magnitude).  So I'm not sure if the pairs of pointers are for left & right channel, real & imaginary, or both.  In other words, the description of that function is incredibly vague.

Comment: For everyone who commented, thanks a lot for the feedback. It turns out that I didn't know enough about my code to adequately ask questions concerning it, and I didn't do enough research on FFTs to understand how they completely work. If someone has the power to close this question then feel free.

Answer (score 3):

For testing purposes you don't need to extract waveform data from WAV files. You can just generate a few signals in memory (e.g. 0, non-zero constant, sinusoid, 2 superimposed sinusoids, white noise) and then test your FFT function on them and see whether or not you're getting what you should (0 for 0, peak at zero frequency for non-zero constant signal, 2 peaks for every sinusoid, uniform non-zero magnitude across all frequencies for white noise).

If you really want to parse WAV files, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) on the format (follow the links). Use either raw PCM encoding or A/µ-law PCM encoding (AKA G.711).

FFT is usually implemented using an in-place algorithm, meaning that the output replaces the input. If you do the same, you don't really need the second pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly found WAVE/RIFF file format has a 44 byte header followed by 16-bit or 2-byte little-endian signed integer samples, interleaved for stereo.  So if you know how to skip bytes, and read short ints into doubles, you should be good to go.

Just feed your desired length of time domain data to your FFT as the real component vector; the result of the FFT will be a complex frequency domain vector.